# Поймать все ошибки, кроме какой-либо

Tags: python, исключения

Допустим, мой иногда может предусмотрено в некоторых местах ловить ошибку отсутствия файла примерно так:

```
try:
    with open('C:/python/test.txt', 'r') as f:
        test = f.read()
        print(test)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("файл не обнаружен")
```

Как в таком случае сделать отлов любых других ошибок во всём коде(исключая ещё некоторые нужные по коду исключения, к примеру exit)?

Если коротко, то я представляю это примерно так:

```
try:
    #...
    try:
        with open('C:/python/test.txt', 'r') as f:
            test = f.read()
            print(test)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("файл не обнаружен")
    #...
except all but no FileNotFoundError:
    print("Опа! Неожиданная ошибка!")
```

Comment: Написать ещё один except. Если первый except не отловит исключение, тогда его отловит второй

Comment: Так это примерный код, реальный куда больше и именно за моменты с "except FileNotFoundError:" я не переживаю, беспокойство вызывает, что любая  моя мелкая ошибка в любом другом месте способна крашануть программу, что очень нежелательно

Comment: Тогда отлов ошибок это просто некрасивый костыль, нужно писать код так, чтобы «мелких ошибок» в принципе не возникало

Comment: Тем не менее, ничто не мешает ловить «любые мелкие ошибки» с помощью этого самого второго except

Comment: Да я понимаю, что костыль, но программа рассчитана на постоянную работу и любое прерывание очень болезненно, потому хоть я и стараюсь делать кучу тестов, всё равно хотелось бы иметь возможность хотя бы некрасивого варианта оставить программу работающей при ошибке

Comment: Ну, `except Exception:` отловит всё кроме exit

Answer (score 4):

```
try:
    with open('C:/python/test.txt', 'r') as f:
        test = f.read()
        print(test)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("файл не обнаружен")
except:
    print("остальныные ошибки")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

Вдоволь покопавшись в англиском stake'е и документации except нашёл решение, которое походит лично мне:

```
     import traceback 
     try:
        a = int(input("Какое исключение попробуем?"))
        if a == 1:
            try:
                with open('C:/python/test.txt', 'r') as f:
                    test = f.read()
                    print(test)
    
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("файл не обнаружен")
    
        elif a == 2:
            print(empty_var)
    
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise FileNotFoundError
    
    except Exception:
         print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: В чем смысл два раза отлавливать исключение FileNotFoundError? Если во внутреннем try-except оно обработано, то во внешний try-except оно уже не прилетит.

Comment: Вместо `raise FileNotFoundError` лучше написать просто `raise` чтобы перебрасывалось оригинальное исключение вместо создания нового. Но вообще да, insolor правильно заметил, что второй отлов FileNotFoundError выглядит здесь бессмысленным